# fopen is unable to open windows hosts file

Tags: c, windows, network-programming, fopen

I am having a `FILE* target` here which should open the windows hosts file and write to it:

```
FILE* target;
target = fopen("C:\\windows\\sysnative\\drivers\\etc\\hosts", "r+");
if (target != NULL) {
    printf("true\n");
} else {
    printf("false\n");
}
```

However, upon opening the windows hosts file, it fails to open it. Specifically, `fopen()` returns `NULL` and `false` is printed to the screen. I checked the directory. It is good. Removing the extra `\`s, I was able to open it with Notepad. However `fopen()` cannot open that file. It is able to open any file in the current working directory, or in a nested directory inside it, but it can't open the hosts file. Perhaps I have an issue with my path? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure about the open-mode `"r+"`? That means you want to open for both reading *and writing*. And it's not unlikely that you can't open for writing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I open it for both *reading and writing*, then that implies I can also *write* to it?

Comment: it's a system file, you need admin rights to write to it

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre And how would you suggest I fix it? Should I compile the source code with `gcc` as admin, or run the executable itself as admin? I have tried running the executable as admin, but it still does not solve the issue.

Comment: first try with `r` mode to see if you can read it. Then try to write to it, using elevated privileges when running the exe

Comment: Do you *need* to write to the file? Why? What is the purpose of your program? Why do you need to open the hosts file? What is the real problem you need to solve? If you only need to read it (for some reason) then perhaps you should change your mode to read-only? In its current form this question is very much [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Galaxy I removed the `network-programming` tag because I don't see how your question is related to it. Could you explain why you think it is appropriate and why you added it again?

Comment: @user10605163 This is an exercise for a `network-programming` class.

Comment: But your question is about `fopen` and not network related at all. See the tag info.

Comment: Hard coding "SysNative" is limited to a 32-bit build running on 64-bit Windows. This is a virtual directory that only 'exists' in a 32-bit process that's running under WOW64 on 64-bit Windows. It does not exist for native architecture processes. Call `IsWow64Process` to determine whether to use "SysNative" or"System32".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need admin priv to open hosts file on windows, try running your script as admin.

Comment: So apparently running the Windows Command Prompt as Administrator, then compiling the source code, and running the executable from within it, worked! `fopen()` was able to successfully write to the file.

Comment: Specifically, the hosts file grants standard users generic-read access, so `"r"` mode would work fine, but "r+" mode requires being an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a file operation fails on Windows, you can call `GetLastError()` (errno` on Posix systems) to find out why the operation fails. This will return an error code you can look up to find out why it failed